# Remove File on One Level of Directories only in KSH

Tags: bash, unix, ksh

I have a **rm** command which clears all the files in a particular directory.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

cd /asd/ded/ses/ddd/rty/leg/

rm *.sas7bdat
rm p_bt*
```

Unfortunately it clears all the files under this directory, but now I just want it to clear in "parent directory" i.e. **"/asd/ded/ses/ddd/rty/leg/"** and not in **"/asd/ded/ses/ddd/rty/leg/21_11"** which is the child directory inside it.

I know level rm is possible in bash. Does it change for KSH and if yes then how.

Comment: Since you aren't using the `-r` option with `rm`, nothing in your code should be removing files from any subdirectory, let alone `21_11` which does not match either of the globs in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LonelySoul,

Chepner is correct.  The default for 'rm' in ksh is to only remove the files in the current directory.  You can remove files from the lower directories (recursively) by adding the '-r' option.

If you are observing different behavior, you may have an alias setup somewhere in your profile.  Try entering 'whence rm' to see if there is an alias that is causing you unexpected behavior.

Examples.

```
>pwd
 /tmp
>touch abc.txt
>mkdir ced
>touch ced/abc.txt
>rm abc.txt (will remove abc.txt in /tmp, but leave the file in directory ced.
>whence rm
rm -f
```

Comment: Thanks Robert. It served the purpose.